Loop from given date until (but not including) current date
I would like to loop from a given date through all the days until the current date, but not including the current date.
Piecing together code that I found on the Internet, I came up with the following solution, which does almost what I want:
$date_begin = new DateTime("2005-03-11");
$today = new DateTime("now");
for ($i = $date_begin; $i <= $today; $i->modify("+1 day")) {
...
}

This code loops through all the days from the given date until the current date, including the current date. In order to exclude the current date, I would have thought that I merely need to replace $i <= $today by $i < $today. But this does not work. Even with < instead of <=, the current date is included in the loop. Why is that? What am I misunderstanding? And how can I exclude the current date?

$date_begin has a time of midnight.  $today includes the current time.  You can modify $today to set hour, minute, second to 0.

Thank you! Replacing DateTime("now") with DateTime("today midnight") did the trick.

Loop over a date period with foreach() instead of manually checking that the day is still in range each time. How to find the dates between two specified date? How to find the dates between two specified date? and Build hierarchical multidimensional array with all year, month, day, and hour values within a range of years

$date_begin = new DateTime("2005-03-11");
$today = new DateTime("now");
$today->modify("00:00:00.0");

for ($i = $date_begin; $i < $today; $i->modify("+1 day")) {
 //...
}


Please never post code-only answers on Stack Overflow.
